# Indexed VARCHAR's key_len

Tags: mysql, varchar, explain

```
-- 2 Moderators: please do not re-format my code

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t`;

CREATE TABLE `t` (
      `v` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci'
    , `c` CHAR(3)    NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci'
    , INDEX `IX_t_v` (`v`)
    , INDEX `IX_t_c` (`c`)
)
;


INSERT INTO t
      (v, c)
VALUES
      ('001', '001')
    , ('002', '002')
    , ('003', '003')
    , ('004', '004')
;

EXPLAIN SELECT c FROM t WHERE c = '001';

EXPLAIN SELECT v FROM t WHERE v = '001';
```

The explain commands give me:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t       ref IX_t_c  IX_t_c  3   const   1   100.00  Using index
```

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t       ref IX_t_v  IX_t_v  5   const   1   100.00  Using index
```

The question is: why key_len for the second query is 5?

Based on [CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html), storage requirements for the VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL should be 4 so I expected the key_len would be the same!

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

P.S. MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10.1 gives the same results for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/field.cc#L6790 says:

```
/**
  @note
    varstring and blob keys are ALWAYS stored with a 2 byte length prefix
*/
```

Comment: Is that for all ROW_FOMATs and Engines?  Or is that in the Handler?  Somewhere I heard that the length was 1 if the max len of any column in the table is less than 256 (or maybe 128, to allow for NULL)?

Comment: It's the the `sql` directory, so that's not in any storage engine. It's in the SQL layer.

Comment: Since there each row must be rewritten going between the SQL layer and the InnoDB Engine layer, this does not say whether 1 byte or 2 is being used on disk.

Answer (score 4):

`key_len` is, to some extent, a fabrication of `EXPLAIN`.  The Engine may store VAR columns in some other way.  Ditto for, multi-byte character sets.  And there is the indication of `NULL`, which seems to be done in two or three different ways.

I see `key_len` useful for only one thing:  How many columns of a composite index is it using.  (With the advent of `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`, this information is readily available.)

EXPLAIN's key_len value

- n*m bytes, where n is the limit given (varchar(n)) and m is the potential number of bytes per character for the given character set (1 for latin1, 3 for utf8, 4 for utf8mb4)
- plus 2 if `VAR` (varchar/varbinary)
- plus 1 for `NULL` (even though NULLness might be stored using a single bit for the Engine and `ROW_FORMAT` in use.)

Related length issues:

- utf8, for example, does not always use 3 bytes per character, so the length can be less than n*m given above.
- VAR fields take only the length needed, plus the length indicator.
- However, when a temp table is implemented via MEMORY, VARCHAR turns into a full-length CHAR.  (This statement goes away with MySQL 8.0.)  So, for that *one* situation, EXPLAIN's key_len may actually reflect the space used.

What do you use key_len for?

Comment: Thanks. I'm also using the information to understand how many parts of multi-column index is used. However, the additional byte confuses me as my index is: (VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL COLLATE latin1, TINYINT, TINYINT). So when I saw key_len=5, I thought 2 parts of index are used and could not understand how this is possible as the TINYINT was not in WHERE!. So I asked.

Comment: @fifonik - A `TINYINT NULL` has key_len=2; `TINYINT NOT NULL` counts as 1.

Comment: Sure, it is NOT NULL in my case. Storage requirements for NULLs are mentioned in manual so I was aware about this. So everything except the VARCHARs was as expected.